# Преобразование строки во время и его сортировка

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, время

Есть простое приложение сделанное в реакте с помощью функционального компонента. Само приложение представляет из себя таблицу, которая получает данные через json файл. Функционал приложения предусматривает возможность сортировки колонок таблицы по возрастанию/по убыванию.

Функция сортировки выглядит следующим образом

```
const [directionSort, setDirectionSort] = useState(true);

const sortData = (field) => {
const copyData = tableItems.concat();

let sortData;

if (directionSort) {
  sortData = copyData.sort(
    (a, b) => { return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1 }
  );
} else {
  sortData = copyData.sort(
    (a, b) => { return a[field] < b[field] ? 1 : -1 }
  );
}


setTableItems(sortData)
setDirectionSort(!directionSort)
}
```

Этот код отрабатывает отлично на всех колонках, кроме одной. Есть колонка, в которой указано время, в формате "1m32s" и эти данные приходят из json в строковом формате, именно в таком виде.

```
"result": "1m 32s"
```

Соответственно, сортировка этой колонки при таком формате отрабатывает некорректно, т.к. сортировка по возрастанию даёт такой вывод:

08s

1m 15s

32s

Вопрос, как можно обработать получаемые данные, что бы выводились они в таком же формате, но сортировались корректно ? Допускается также изменить формат данных в json файле

Comment: А еще, вместо двух функций можно записать `let d = directionSort * 2 - 1;` получив 1 или -1 как "направление". И в функции `return d * a[field] < d * b[field] ? 1 : -1 ` или `return d * (a[field] - b[field])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, проблема связана вот с чем: во всех колонках происходит сортировка в лексикографическом порядке, то есть "по алфавиту". А в той, колонке, где записано время  - такая сортировка не подходит.

Я бы предложил такое решение: у вас в коде есть участок кода, который, собственно, принимает решение "что а больше б": `(a, b) => { return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1 }`. Нужно сделать исключение для колонки со временем, и обработать её так: преобразовать время в что то типа int (минуты * 60 + секунды) и принимать решение что "а больше б" уже на основе сравнения этих int'ов.

Там есть некотрая возня, связанная с форматом колонки со временем, но она преодолима.

Если такого объяснения недостаточно, дайте знать в комментариях: я напишу корявый код обработки строк на js

Comment: И еще надо дополнительно превращать `a, b[field]` в числа, если это вдруг строки... потому что `"11" > "9" // false`

Comment: @s.h. Да, если можно, хотелось бы увидеть пример такой обработки

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Дело в том, что в моей таблице есть как строки, так и числа

Comment: @Miltosh А сортировка происходит при клике на th таблицы? Можно на эти элементы добавить тип сортировки, `data-sort="number | alphabet | time"` и в зависимости от этой строки, присвоить соответствующую сортирующую функцию...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Да, сортировка должна отрабатывать при клике на <th>. Вариант с типом сортировки хорош, думаю, он мне подойдёт. Но мне ещё не до конца понятно как именно мне работать с временными данными. Думаю, что может проще будет в json файле передавать число - количество секунд ?